# Format time in hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, time-format

How do I set format on time?
It shows 16:9:2
It should show 16:09:02

my code:

```
setInterval(function _timer() {

var time = new Date();
var h = time.getHours();
var m = time.getMinutes();
var s = time.getSeconds();
var fullTime = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
fullTime.format("hh-MM-ss");// this is not working
$("#time").html(fullTime);

1000
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
var time = new Date();
var h = time.getHours();
var m = time.getMinutes();
var s = time.getSeconds();
alert(
        ("0" + h).slice(-2)   + ":" + 
        ("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + 
        ("0" + s).slice(-2));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to use an external dependency, the [momentjs library](http://momentjs.com/) is one of the best out there!

You could replace all your formatting with:

```
var now = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
```